# Unavailable packages repository

Tags: 11.10, apt, package-management

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric) on this machine, and suddenly, `apt` is unable to `update` properly.

If I ask it to update its package information, by running `apt-get update` (or alternatively telling the update manager to "check"), it succeeds for about 120 packages (more precisely, I get about 120 Ign/Hit notes) and then says it cannot find *universe Sources* and *restricted amd64*:

```
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://de.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]
Err http://de.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I manually checked the [`de` server](http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/universe/source/) and cannot find anything wrong with the stuff it's complaining about. Also it looks pretty much like, say, the [`us` mirror](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/universe/source/).
But oddly enough, the IP it lists, seems to point to a *debian* package server, which obviously does not contain ubuntu packages.

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: I believe that this should be reported to: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-mirrors or irc://chat.freenode.net/ubuntu-mirrors :)

Comment: @medigeek: Thanks, I dropped the link in the irc room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that there is something wrong with the `de` servers (persistently: look at how old the question is!). I changed all `de` entries in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the `nl` servers and it updates fine now.

It would appear, once you update from a different server, you can revert back to your local one. The nice ubuntu-mirrors people were unable to explain this, but it works.